# Access Vuex store from javascript module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have an out javascript module, and I want to get the auth key from the vuex store

This is my code, that's seems that it work

```
import store from '../../../store';

class ExternalApi {
  constructor() {
    const that = this;
    that.configuration = { apiKey: '', basePath: '/api/v2' };

    that.authorizationHeader = function authorizationHeader() {
      const cstore = store;
      if (cstore && cstore.state && cstore.state.accessToken) {
        that.configuration.apiKey = cstore.state.accessToken;
      }
      const localVarHeaderParams = { };
      localVarHeaderParams.authorization = `Bearer ${that.configuration.apiKey}`;

      return localVarHeaderParams;
    };
    this.list = function list(params) {
      const localVarPath = `${that.configuration.basePath}/list`;
      const localVarHeaderParams = that.authorizationHeader();
      return axios....
    };
}
```

I want to know 2 things:

1. Does it the way to connect to store from javascript or there is a better way for doing it
2. Does this code can make me some securities problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your first question, when you want to use the store from outside Vue just use its API as you are doing though you don't really need to check for the store or the state to be initialized.

Regarding security, storing the authorization token in JS will be vulnerable to [XSS](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) attacks, the best way to avoid (or mitigate) them is implementing a robust [Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Content_Security_Policy_Cheat_Sheet.html) and using a low (5-10min) time to live for your tokens.

On a side note, you don't need to rename `store` to `cstore` and if you use `class methods` instead of adding function properties in the constructor you wont need to juggle with `this`. Also note that storing the token in memory will not survive a page refresh so you may want to store it in `sessionStorage`.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer, how can i wont juggle with this if I need to export the method like: export const {
  list,.....
} = new ExternalApi();

Comment: If you want to export functions don't use a class at all. If you wanna go with a class you can export the instance and then use its methods `export const externalApi = new ExternalApi()` and then `import {externalApi} from 'the-file'; externalApi.list()`. You can also define those functions as methods and bind them in the constructor: `this.list = this.list.bind(this)` and export them as you want, but that may seem quite strange.